# Bootstrap 3 - Is it possible to right-align a form and a dropdown list like this?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

After some time I managed to place the dropdown list totally on the right and right-align the form and the dropdown menu. I also used a glyphicon for the dropdown list.

My questions are:

1. Is it correct to align components in the way I did or is there a best practice to do this?
2. Can I use a glyphicon in a dropdown class or do I need to use a button dropdown list for that?

You can check my code below. I hope you can advice me or give a good tip. Thank you.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ path('homepage') }}">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li>
                    <form class="navbar-form">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Email" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Sign in</button>
                    </form>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe" aria-hidden="true"></span> 
                        <b class="caret"></b>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                        <li><a href="#">Acción #1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Acción #2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Acción #3</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Acción #4</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `navbar-right` with your `navbar-form` and place it ouside of the UL. See example.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ path('homepage') }}">Project name</a>

    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe" aria-hidden="true"></span> 
            <b class="caret"></b>
          </a>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
            <li><a href="#">Acción #1</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Acción #2</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Acción #3</a>

            </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Acción #4</a>

            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Email" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Sign in</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <!--/.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you very much @vanburenx. I tried it and this look nicer with the dropdown list in the first position when the navbar collapse.

Comment: This is the default way Bootstrap is setup to handle it. Glad I could help.